# Merge webcam stream and a video file and send the result by RTP or RTSP

Tags: java, video, stream, rtp, jmf

**Hi,**

We are students working on a Java project where we have to:

1. Capture the video stream from a webcam
2. Merge this stream with a video file (we take the average of colors of each pixel, so the two streams are superimposed)
3. Transmit the result of this merge on the network, using RTP or RTSP (theoretically, it will be received by 2 Android tablets).

One thing that's very important is that all these operations should be **in real-time** (or almost). The RTP stream should be received in the same time that the webcam is capturing the video.

In order to do this, we use the Java Media Framework (JMF) API. The first and second points have been successfully implemented : each second, 30 **BufferedImage** from the webcam are merged with 30 **BufferedImage** from the video file. The result is displayed on a classic JFrame (we do that using only Swing and JMF), and it works very good.

We still have to do the third point. Sending a video stream via RTP is not very hard.
**But here is the matter:** due to points 1 and 2, we do not have a video stream, but a serie of BufferedImages. We know how to get a video file from these BufferedImage. But it's only a video file recorded on the hard drive, and it can't be sent on the network in real-time. So how can we make an *on-the-fly* stream from these BufferedImage that can be directly sent via RTP?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to improve my answer.

First there is the question whether you really have to use RTP/RTSP. If you don't have to, you can send your image data just through a DatagramSocket and assume the receiver knows how to decode them. Use something like

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1], 1);    

packet.setAddress(receiver.getAddress());
packet.setPort(port);

while(running)
{
   byte[] data = getMergedImageData();

   packet.setData(data);
   packet.setLength(data.length);

   socket.send(packet);
}
```

If you have to use RTP you should have a look at the [mjsip](http://www.mjsip.org/) project. Basically you have to create a valid RTP header (e.g. the first 12 bytes in your databuffer). This is rather simple if you know where each bit belongs to.

Depending on how you encode your images you might have to be wary of additional requirements. For example, when sending Jpeg through RTP you have to remove the complete Jpeg header and create an abbreviated RTP/Jpeg header and place it between the RTP header and the payload. The receiver will have to recreate the Jpeg header from the abbreviated header. For Jpeg, also make sure to add an EOI marker to your image if not already present. I think in this regard [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) can do a lot of work for you if you dare to dive into JNI.

For more information on how the RTP payloads have to be tailored see [this](http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters/rtp-parameters.xml).

Cheers
~